# Column binding ODBC is not correct

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, odbc

I have a column in sql server 2008 table of a `varchar(100)` that when updated throws

> String data, right truncation

The column is mapped to a `CStringA` member variable. 
When i try to update its content with a *64 characters string* i get the exception above.

I have found that the limit for this column length as i was able to write to the table is *50 characters* long, any additional char will trigger this exception.

The issue is, i have another column in that same table that is of a type `varchar(50)` and i suspect that its length is what my member variable is bound to.

Is there a way to bind columns length manually or any other solution?!

Comment: My guess is you should have use `NVARCHAR(100)` instead of `VARCHAR(100)`

Comment: @TT. I thought so too at first, but if he has a `CStringA` this should work fine with `CHAR`. If it had been bound to a `CStringW` I would expect it to have worked only for the first 50 (wide)chars.
@Pavel: How do you bind the columns? Show some code please.

Comment: @erg I have to admit it's been since 2002 that I have had any contact with C++/MFC so I can't comment on that.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for replying. This issue is solved!
The guy that wrote the code before my used the 'DISTINCT* SELECT....'
in his query. When you use distinct * as an open statement you should rearrange you RFX calls in DoFieldExchange in the same order as the columns were defined in that table, plus a few column were missing that was what caused my exception.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved!
The guy that wrote the code before my used the 'DISTINCT* SELECT....'
in his query. When you use distinct * as an open statement you should rearrange you RFX calls in DoFieldExchange in the same order as the columns were defined in that table, plus a few column were missing that was what caused my exception.